# Change Element href Right Before Drag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an extension that allows me to drag photo links in some website that doesn't allow it. The element **(photoCell)** has a default href of "**javascript://"** and has a child element **(photo)** which holds the image.

I want to be able to change the **href** of the parent element to the **src** of the child image so when i drag, i drag the URL of the child image. (This works if i do it without a drag listener but then when i click on an element it loads the image and not the expected javascript function). So i need to change the href back to "javascript://" after drag is done.

However, even though the href changes the dragged URL still is **"javascript://"**

```
function dragstart() {
    this.href = this.children[0].src;
}

function dragend() {
    this.href = "javascript://";
}

function doForPicturedesk() {
    var gallaryCells = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-cell");
    for (var i = 0; i < gallaryCells.length; i++) {
        var gallaryCell = gallaryCells[i];
        var photoCell = element.children[0];    
        photoCell.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstart);
        photoCell.addEventListener("dragend",dragend);
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of the HTML

```
<div class="gallery-cell jg-entry entry-visible" style="width: 534px; height: 345px; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
    <a href="javascript://" onclick="openPictureDetail('343563491-516813675371465101')" class="gallery-cell__link gallery-cell__image--hoverable">
              <img id="thumb_343563491-516813675371465101" class="gallery-cell__image " src="/bild-disp/diasdb/thumbnailextl.action?ref=343563491-516813675371465101&amp;w=false" onerror="correctMissing(this, '343563491-516813675371465101');" style="width: 534px; height: 356px; margin-left: -267px; margin-top: -178px;">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't think was possible, but what do I know. All you have to do is use `dataTransfer.setData` to achieve your goal. Try it below:

```js
let anchor = document.querySelector('a');
anchor.ondragstart = function(event) {
  let urlWeWant = 'https://www.example.com';
  event.dataTransfer.types.forEach(type => {
  
  //Note that all you HAVE to do for this to work is:
  //event.dataTransfer.setData(type, urlWeWant);
  //BUT, I think checking the type and replace HTML is better
  
    if (type.includes('html')) {
      let clone = event.target.cloneNode(true);
      clone.href = urlWeWant;
      let dataHTML = clone.outerHTML
      event.dataTransfer.setData(type, dataHTML);
    } else {
      event.dataTransfer.setData(type, urlWeWant);
    };
  });
};
```

```html
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>Drag Me Into Another Window :)</a>
```

Comment: Note that clicking on the link doesn't do anything. Only dragging into a new window will make an effect.